# How would i say "in ten minutes"?

Tags: katakana, hiragana

I'm writing a paragraph for my Japanese oral exam and want to say "i have class in ten minutes", or "i will go to my class in ten minutes", how would i say this?

Comment: Hello Sen, welcome to the Japanese Stack Exchange!  Unfortunately, simple requests for translation are out of scope -- see also ["We don't do translations"](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799).

Comment: You should edit your question to put what you think it might be, or show your own research attempts.  Then it won't be closed as a translation request.

Answer (score 1):

I have class in ten minutes is 私は１０分後に授業がある。
I will go to my calss in ten minutes is 私は１０分後に授業に行く。

In japanese, the most natural way to say it might be （自分の）授業は１０分後に始まる。 which is my calss begins in 10 minutes.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry but I can't read kanji yet, could you provide the hiragana for those few sentences instead?